# How to find IP address of another side of a LAN cable? (RPi and Ubuntu are connected)

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi

I have a raspberry PI 3B. When I connect it via LAN, the `ifconfig` on UBuntu does not show any IPv4 address (Just IPv6). What should I do to find the correct IP range of my RPi? (and then use `nmap` to find exact IP and finally connect via SSH)

(Sadly I don't have any display to tweak with raspbian GUI!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might not be "the best" solution, but it works:

If you haven't configured a static IP address and in the absence of a DHCP server, your Raspberry Pi will have a self assigned link-local IP-address in the range of `169.254.1.0` to `169.254.254.255`.

If the Ethernet interface on your Ubuntu machine did not self assign a link-local IP-address, you can set it yourself in the same subnet as the Raspberry Pi, e.g. by (change `eth0` to the name of your interface)

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 169.254.10.10
```

Now you can ping for your Raspberry Pi, which will also report the IP-address of your Raspberry Pi

```
ping raspberrypi.local
```

Alternatively you can directly ssh into your Raspberry Pi

```
ssh pi@raspberrypi.local
```

If the `raspberrypi.local` addressing does not work, you can search for the IP-address with `arp-scan` (you might have to install it first):

```
sudo arp-scan --interface=eth0 169.254.0.0/16
```

Comment: Attempting to assign a [Link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) is futile!

Comment: I am not saying this is the best way to go. But technically it works without problems both in Raspbian and Ubuntu using ifconfig.

Comment: It is futile, because the link ALREADY has a [Link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) (this is an essential part of the address resolution protocols) and works DESPITE attempts to assign a new one.

Answer (score 1):

***ifconfig*** is deprecated. On your pi issue the following command to determine the details of your addressing:

***ip addr list***

This will show both IPv4 and IPv6 addressing details:

[image: ip addr list output]

HTH-  Terrence