# Connecting to RPi from Linux with the ethernet cable without touching RPi

Tags: pi-3, ssh, ethernet, connection, ethernet-port

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 that runs on Raspbian and has **SSH enabled**. However, I don't have any monitor to connect it to (to set up WiFi connection), so my only chance to communicate with it is a basic ethernet cable.

My PC is running *Ubuntu Linux*, and after searching the internet, I was only able to find tutorials on how to make this work on Windows. So my question is, how do I connect to *RPi3* from *Linux* using the *ethernet cable*?

Any tips or links to tutorials are appreciated.

Comment: In case you directly connect your Raspberry Pi to your Ubuntu machine, please try this approach: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/85712/77005

Answer (score 3):

Connect your pi to your network with the Ethernet cable and power up.

Next, [find the Pis IP address](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13936/find-raspberry-pi-address-on-local-network)

Then connect with a terminal:`ssh pi@ADDRESS`

It will ask you about the new ECDSA key, accept and you should be good!

There's a nice walk-though at [MagPI magazine](https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/ssh-remote-control-raspberry-pi/)

Answer (score 3):

You can connect a computer via a direct Ethernet connection and `ssh` using a [Link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) with `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local` (assuming user Pi and unchanged hostname).

This connection has some restrictions, but `ssh` works. One drawback is that with no internet connection there will be no time/date setup.

It would be better to connect the Pi to your router; then `raspberrypi.local` can be used, but with more protocols. See [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) "Connecting a Computer to the Pi"

Comment: Does the direct Ethernet connection require some specific setup? The article you linked to talks about stateless address autoconfiguration but that does not seem to be happening or suffice in my case. I get "ssh: Could not resolve hostname myraspi.local: Temporary failure in name resolution".

Answer (score -1):

**For direct ethernet connection from laptop to raspberry pi:**

1. Remove the SD card from your RPi and insert it into to your machine running Ubuntu
2. Two partitions will get mounted **boot** and **root** .
3. Open boot partition and open ***cmdline.txt*** file using any text editor
4. Assuming you have netmask `255.255.255.0 or 255.255.0.0` and your laptop's ip address typically be `192.168.1.y`. Goto the end of the line and add `ip=192.168.1.x` replace x with the desired number between 1 to 255 other than `y`. GOTO step 6

   OR
5. If you obtain address automatically (DHCP) then type ip between `169.254.0.0 – 169.254.255.254` *eg. `ip=169.254.1.3`* at the end of the line in cmdline.txt
6. Save the file and reinsert SD card into RPi and boot it.

Now you can ssh from Ubuntu terminal by typing `ssh pi@x.x.x.x`where x.x.x.x is  ip value you set in cmdline.txt file.

Here are links for detailed reference [elinux.org](https://elinux.org/RPi_cmdline.txt) and [RPi forums](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=24993)